# Namespace 'global.JSX' has no exported member 'TargetedEvent'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, preact

Here is the line of code:

```
  const handleChangeProduct = (e: JSX.TargetedEvent<HTMLSelectElement, Event>) => {
    const val = e.currentTarget.value;
    setDbEditProduct(val);
  };
```

Getting this error:

```
Namespace 'global.JSX' has no exported member 'TargetedEvent'
```

Here are my imports:

```
import { h, FunctionalComponent, Fragment } from 'preact';
import { useState } from 'preact/hooks';
import NativeSelect from '@material-ui/core/NativeSelect';
```

Here is my TSConfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2019", "DOM", "ES6", "DOM.Iterable", "ScriptHost"],
    "strict": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "jsxFactory": "h",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "include": ["./css.d.ts", "./global.d.ts", "./frontend/**/*"]
}
```

Comment: show your tsconfig pls

Comment: @Egor Added my tsconfig, as requested

Answer (score 0):

The error was sort-of helpful... here's what fixed it:

```
import { h, FunctionalComponent, JSX, Fragment } from 'preact';
```

*(Added JSX to the imports)*